# Display "Correct" and "Incorrect" depending on answer

Tags: android

I want to display "Correct" when the keypad_hash is pressed once if the answer is right and "Incorrect" when it's wrong, and when the keypad_hash is pressed AGAIN, it goes to the next random question.

Part of my XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Guess"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Guess: "
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Answer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Incorrect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CORRECT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="40dp"/>
```

The Java code is

```
package org.example.question;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    //variable for different questions
    int fnum0, snum0,fnum1, snum1,fnum2, snum2,fnum3, snum3,
    fnum4, snum4,fnum5, snum5,fnum6, snum6,fnum7, snum7,
    fnum8, snum8,fnum9, snum9, answer;

    //Variable and type declaration for buttons and text
    Button keyOne;
    Button keyTwo;
    Button keyThree;
    Button keyFour;
    Button keyFive;
    Button keySix;
    Button keySeven;
    Button keyEight;
    Button keyNine;
    Button keyDel;
    Button keyZero;
    Button keyHash;
    Button keySubtract;
    TextView display;
    TextView display1;
    TextView answer0;
    int q=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Display text on screen

        display1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Guess);
        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Title);
        answer0 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Answer);

        //Code for correct and incorrect

        //Assigning names to each keypad
        keyOne= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_1);
        keyTwo= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_2);
        keyThree= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_3);
        keyFour= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_4);
        keyFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_5);
        keySix= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_6);
        keySeven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_7);
        keyEight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_8);
        keyNine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_9);
        keyZero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_0);
        keySubtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_subtract);
        keyHash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_hash);
        keyDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);

        //setting button to produce an event when each button is pressed
        keyOne.setOnClickListener(this);     keyTwo.setOnClickListener(this);     keyThree.setOnClickListener(this);
        keyFour.setOnClickListener(this);     keyFive.setOnClickListener(this);     keySix.setOnClickListener(this);
        keySeven.setOnClickListener(this);      keyEight.setOnClickListener(this);  keyNine.setOnClickListener(this);
        keySubtract.setOnClickListener(this);    keyHash.setOnClickListener(this);  keyDel.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Created a new string object
        String str = new String();

        switch (arg0.getId()) {

            //what happens when hash button is pressed

            case R.id.keypad_hash:
            {
                //Generates random numbers

                fnum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
                snum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));

                //Generates a random number between 0 to 9 with random operators for first and sceond number.
                int operation = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));

                /* Generate random expression with random operators and display "?" if the answer is one digit
                 * or"??" if the answer is greater than 10.
                 */
                if(operation == 0)
                    str = fnum0+  "+"  +  snum0+  "=" + ((fnum0+snum0<10)? "?" : "??");
                if("Correct".equals(display.getText().toString()))
                {
                    display.setText("Correct");
                }
                else
                {
                    display.setText("Incorrect");
                }

                if(operation == 1)
                    str = fnum0 +  "-"  +  snum0+  "=" + ((fnum0-snum0<10)? "?" : "??");
                if("Correct".equals(display.getText().toString()))
                {
                    display.setText("Correct");
                }
                else
                {
                    display.setText("Incorrect");
                }
                if(operation == 2)
                   str = fnum0 +  "*"  +  snum0+  "=" +  ((fnum0*snum0<10)? "?" : "??");
                if("Correct".equals(display.getText().toString()))
                {
                    display.setText("Correct");
                }
                else
                {
                    display.setText("Incorrect");
                }
                if("Correct".equals(display.getText().toString()))
                {
                    display.setText("Correct");
                }
                else
                {
                    display.setText("Incorrect");
                }
                str = fnum0 +  "/"  +  snum0+  "=" +  ((fnum0/snum0<10)? "?" : "??");
                if("Correct".equals(display.getText().toString()))
                {
                    display.setText("Correct");
                }
                else
                {
                    display.setText("Incorrect");
                }
                display.setText(str);
                break;
            }

            case R.id.keypad_1:
                String str1 = display.getText().toString();
                display.setText(str1.replace("?", "1"));
                break;

            case R.id.keypad_2:
                String str2 = display.getText().toString();
                display.setText(str2.replace("?", "2"));
                break;

            case R.id.keypad_3:
                String str3 = display.getText().toString();
                display.setText(str3.replace("?", "3"));
                break;

            case R.id.keypad_4:
                String str4 = display.getText().toString();
                display.setText(str4.replace("?", "4"));
                break;

            case R.id.keypad_5:
                String str5 = display.getText().toString();
                display.setText(str5.replace("?", "5"));
                break;

            case R.id.keypad_6:
                String str6 = display.getText().toString();
                display.setText(str6.replace("?", "6"));
                break;

            case R.id.keypad_7:
                String str7 = display.getText().toString();
                display.setText(str7.replace("?", "7"));
                break;

            case R.id.keypad_8:
                String str8 = display.getText().toString();
                display.setText(str8.replace("?", "8"));
                break;

            case R.id.keypad_9:
                String str9 = display.getText().toString();
                display.setText(str9.replace("?", "9"));
                break;

            case R.id.delete:
                break;

            case R.id.keypad_0:
                String str0 = display.getText().toString();
                display.setText(str0.replace("?", "0"));
                break;

            case R.id.keypad_subtract:
                display.setText("-");
                break;
        }
    }

    public void requestFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

It's not displaying the "Correct" and "Incorrect", but when I click keypad_hash ONCE it takes me to the next random question.

Comment: I am a bit confused, it appears like you set it to ?? no matter what, so that's what is displayed.

Comment: yh.. but i need to display "?" if the answer of random expression is of one digit and "??" if two digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the operation, replace the line of code by:

```
str = fnum0+  "+"  +  snum0+  "=" + ((fnum0+snum0<10) ? "?" : "??")
```

or

```
str = fnum0+  "*"  *  snum0+  "=" + ((fnum0*snum0<10) ? "?" : "??")
```

or
   ...

For your information:

```
int a = ( b ? c : d );
// is shorthand for:
if ( b )
{
    a = c;
}
else
{
    a = d;
}
```

Comment: i tried first two line of code and it only displays "?" or"??" on the screen, the expressions are not being displayed

Comment: Yes, you have to add it yourself.. lol.. Just edited my answer as you look really lazy ;-)

Comment: looool... been reseraching for this question since after but no clue... and nearly gave up but u  motivated me ;-)..  thanks dude!

Comment: can u tell me how to display "CORRECT" when keypad_hash is pressed only once. the way i have done its not working.. i will show u that part of the code

Comment: Pleasqe, as you totally modified your question, the answer does not mean anything and people will think my answer is crazy! Please get back to the old question and create a new one! Short answer: do you realize what you are writing in your if statement? The code after: case R.id.keypad_hash: is to start a new equation so, that's a logical behavior!

Comment: sorry, i didnt know that we are not suppose to do that i will change it to the old question

Answer (score 0):

After you compute your two random numbers and the operation, you need to compute the answer.  Then create a new string variable.  If the answer is 10 or higher, set this to "??" otherwise set it to "?".  Then append this variable to the end of your string instead of the "??" you have hard coded in.